# MediaType.TEXT_CSV for Jersey

Tags: jersey

Would it be possible to accept csv types?
service.path(appPath).accept(mediaType).get(String.class)

There's no MediaType.TEXT_CSV defined in javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType. Have I missed something?

I am currently on Jersey 1.1.6.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could define your own media type:

```java
public final static String TEXT_CSV = "text/csv";
public final static MediaType TEXT_CSV_TYPE = new MediaType("text", "csv");
```

Answer (score 4):

csv is nothing but comma seperated **text** file

you can always use `text\plain` as media type to deal with CSV files - and deal with the CSV using frameworks such as [Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Or (in case of fileupload)

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String process(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream csv) throws IOException {
//Process CSV file
}
```

Comment: Actually I've got a fatal error due to `@FormDataParam("file")` but when I removed that it's working as expected.