# Sending Text/CSV file by an POST API call from Java using Jersey

Tags: java, http-post, multipartform-data, jersey-client, javax.ws.rs

I want to send a file as part of my request Body by making a POST request. The content-type of file is text/csv. I am creating a MultiPart but there is no option to send a text/csv file. I tried creating a custom content-type  - text/csv but it is throwing an exception.
Below is my dummy code.

```
package com.practice;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

import javax.ws.rs.client.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

public class CATestonlyForLocal1 {

    public final static String TEXT_CSV = "text/csv";
    public static final String CA_ENDPOINT_URL = "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/ProductUpload?";
    public static final String CA_INVENTORY_TEMPLATE_CODE = "&templatecode=CAINV";
    public static final String CA_PRICE_TEMPLATE_CODE = "CAPRICE";
    public static final String CA_IMPORT_TYPE = "&importtype=AddUpdate";
    public static final String CA_CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE = "text/csv";
    public static final String CA_ACCESS_TOKEN = "wd52SrkWgoXeidEZ2nNIh_2gdveWIGWlKRYvUQQudYw-33727";
    public static final String CA_FILE_FOLDER = "C:/D Drive/OMS Documents/Story Related  Docs/Channel Advisor/InventoryUpload.txt";
    public static final String CA_CONTENT_TYPE_KEY = "Content-Type";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // getProductId();
            uploadInventory();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void uploadInventory() {

        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
        File fileEntity = new File(CA_FILE_FOLDER);
        final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("text/csv", fileEntity);
        final MediaType TEXT_CSV_TYPE = new MediaType("text", "csv");
        filePart.setMediaType(TEXT_CSV_TYPE);
        FormDataMultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        multipart.bodyPart(filePart);
        WebTarget target = client.target(CA_ENDPOINT_URL + "access_token=" + CA_ACCESS_TOKEN + CA_INVENTORY_TEMPLATE_CODE + CA_IMPORT_TYPE);

        System.out.println("multipart.getMediaType(): " + multipart.getMediaType());
        System.out.println(TEXT_CSV);

        final Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(multipart,multipart.getMediaType()));

        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Below is the exception I am getting on using custom content-type

```
Apr 11, 2020 1:00:27 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/csv, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/csv, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:503)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)
    at com.practice.CATestonlyForLocal.uploadInventory(CATestonlyForLocal.java:58)
    at com.practice.CATestonlyForLocal.main(CATestonlyForLocal.java:32)
```

I have read a lot of documentation but did not get much.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a supported MediaType.

Try

```
javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE
```

Comment: I want media type as text/csv which is not available.

Comment: It looks like this may be the answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520950/mediatype-text-csv-for-jersey